# highcharts-react-native not working in iOS binary (.ipa)

Tags: ios, highcharts, react-native-ios, ipa

I have a react-native app. This app has an iOS version, which uses [Highcharts](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native).

```
# package.json

...
"dependencies": {
  "@highcharts/highcharts-react-native": "^3.1.2"
  "highcharts": "^8.2.0"
}
...
```

In Xcode, when I run the app locally, the chart shows up fine. But when I build an iOS binary (.ipa), the same charting area is empty.

This tells me that the Highcharts library didn't get included in the packaged binary.

I've been playing around with package.json, Podfile, and Xcode Libraries and Frameworks. But nothing seems to work.

I'm really getting killed on time here. Has someone come across this and fixed it?

**EDIT (10/21/2020)**

I've attached screenshots of i) the working and ii) the non-working screens.

My problem also seems similar to this SO question.
[App behaves different when run from XCode compared to .ipa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618423/app-behaves-different-when-run-from-xcode-compared-to-ipa)

As per the answer there, when I changed the build configuration for Archive to debug the generated `.ipa` started to work!1

But if I do not want to use debug for the build I send to Apple, then how do I build + archive so that all libraries are working.

Working
[image]

Not Working
[image]

Comment: First, have you checked the general prerequisites - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native#general-prerequisites and did you follow those steps https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native#installing? If the answer is yes, try to apply this workaround from this comment: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/104#issuecomment-688671114

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yep, I arrived at the similar issue, but with a slightly different patch. See my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working, tested in via Xcode and TestFlight.

As per @SebastianWędzel 's comment, there was an issue in the library itself. But I used a slightly different patch, here.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/104#issuecomment-714195854

The ultimate solution was patching the `getAssetAsString` function in this Highcharts library file.

```
node_modules/@highcharts/highcharts-react-native/src/HighchartsReactNative.js
```